# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr.ec_portfolio_title,

Tags: javascript

I am using eclipse theme and i am getting this error because of this error i am unable to use add media, set featured image, edit and screen option functionalities on pages.
    the syntax is :

```
$('#checkbox-ec_portfolio_title_toggle').change(function () {
    var items = $("tr.ec_portfolio_title,");
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        items.show();
    } else {
        items.hide();
    }
})
```

the above code is giving error please suggest me solution.

Comment: Syntax error.  What's with the comma?

Answer (score 3):

I would read up on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ to find out how to properly use the selector string from jquery.  As far as I know, there is no selector syntax that ends with a comma `,`.

```
$("tr.ec_portfolio_title,");
//                      └─ what is that for?
```

Comment: I'd assume the downvote is for attitude rather than correctness. While I wouldn't downvote for that, I'm sympathetic. Please reconsider your approach.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Not my downvote but there is an element of correctness involved: jQuery 1.7.2 ignored the trailing comma whereas more recent versions complain.